# Using a BASH script to edit a Mongo database when there is no Mongo client installed

Tags: mongodb, bash, raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

I have an application running on a Raspberry Pi and it's storing data in a Mongo database, but the Mongo client is not also installed on the Pi. I'm using Alpine Linux for my OS.

I want to search for entries in the database using a single parameter in that entry (i.e. a filename) and then completely delete the entry from the database.

How can I accomplish this with a BASH script when the Mongo client is not installed on the Pi?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say run something like Robo 3T and remote connect to the Pi to manipulate its data. If there's no Mongo shell installed, I doubt a Bash script can do anything either.

Comment: Thanks, but the script need to also run on the Pi.

Comment: If you can verify that Mongo CLI is running, then perhaps the BASH script idea can work. https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/install-and-set-up-mongodb-on-a-raspberry-pi-part-2-1167#mongo+cli+in+raspberry+pi

Comment: "mongo: not found" is the response.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is install the mongo shell, or use one of the drivers such as [pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

If you're really good with bash, you might be able to use `nc`, `telnet`, or `expect` to connect to the mongod port, and speak [Mongo Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#mongodb-wire-protocol), which is not nearly as fun as it sounds.

Comment: Since the wire protocol is binary, attempting to speak it is impractical.